# Is there a way to force seasonality from auto.arima

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

With the `forecast` package, I have a time series that I would like `?auto.arima` to automatically pick the orders but I would like to coerce seasonality. The defaults for the function allow for the `seasonal` argument to be set to `TRUE`, but that only allows the option for seasonality not a coercion.

```
auto.arima(x, d=NA, D=NA, max.p=5, max.q=5,
     max.P=2, max.Q=2, max.order=5, max.d=2, max.D=1, 
     start.p=2, start.q=2, start.P=1, start.Q=1, 
     stationary=FALSE, seasonal=TRUE,
     ic=c("aicc", "aic", "bic"), stepwise=TRUE, trace=FALSE,
     approximation=(length(x)>100 | frequency(x)>12), xreg=NULL,
     test=c("kpss","adf","pp"), seasonal.test=c("ocsb","ch"),
     allowdrift=TRUE, allowmean=TRUE, lambda=NULL, biasadj=FALSE,
     parallel=FALSE, num.cores=2)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the `D` parameter, which governs seasonal differencing, to a value greater than zero. (The default `NA` allows `auto.arima()` to use or not use seasonality.) For example:

```
> set.seed(1)
> foo <- ts(rnorm(60),frequency=12)
> auto.arima(foo)
Series: foo 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7307:  log likelihood=-75.72
AIC=153.45   AICc=153.52   BIC=155.54
> auto.arima(foo,D=1)
Series: foo 
ARIMA(0,0,0)(1,1,0)[12]                    

Coefficients:
         sar1
      -0.3902
s.e.   0.1478

sigma^2 estimated as 1.139:  log likelihood=-72.23
AIC=148.46   AICc=148.73   BIC=152.21
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that the same things in the question and answer here are true for the python implementation of this function?

Comment: @MattCremeens: looking at [the documentation for `auto_arima` in `pmdarima`](http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html?highlight=auto_arima#pmdarima.arima.auto_arima), we see a parameter `D` with the same semantics as the one in R's `forecast::auto.arima()`. The documentation doesn't say explicitly whether setting `D` to a value greater than zero forces seasonal differencing, but it seems like the only reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan Kolassa. I re-read the documentation myself and they did mention something along the lines that the auto_arima function in python is patterned off of the R counterpart, so I guess that'll be good enough for me. After a few runs of my own python program, that does appear to be the case given the results. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, will `D=1` also work if there is average monthly data for 42 years?

Comment: @Mandalorian: it certainly should, and here is a quick test that it does: ? `library(forecast); print(auto.arima(ts(rnorm(42*12),frequency=12),D=1))`