# R forecast::auto.arima() not including seasonal differencing

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

While trying to create ARIMA models for half-hour time series data, auto.arima would not automatically include seasonality, despite apparent (daily) seasonality. When specifying D = 1 when calling auto.arima (as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046275/is-there-a-way-to-force-seasonality-from-auto-arima)), the ARIMA model returns the following error:

```
Error in if (length(dx) > ncol(dxreg)) lm(dx ~ dxreg - 1, na.action = na.omit) else list(rank = 0L) : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Have included a minimal reproducible example below

```
structure(c(860.110666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1795.942, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1233.68133333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2460.29066666667, 1910.628, 3026.91, 
1313.402, 587.111666666667, 1389.328, 0, 425.473666666667, 2676.30433333333, 
359.064, 598.866666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 826.639333333333, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 525.482333333333, 600.823333333333, 0, 1293.36533333333, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 383.521333333333, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 739.561, 3241.267, 2820.05166666667, 3262.343, 
1779.022, 1406.778, 631.806666666667, 3261.663, 25.2043333333333, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1120.446, 931.430666666667, 329.675, 
167.672, 2957.59733333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 486.451666666667, 
1210.21233333333, 0, 1192.211, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1899.427, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 717.466333333333, 0, 0, 0, 2421.93233333333, 3231.43766666667, 
1160.77066666667, 2315.53966666667, 3252.93833333333, 3210.40633333333, 
1805.097, 1445.225), .Tsp = c(1505352600, 1505352600.00816, 17520
), class = "ts")

aa <- forecast::auto.arima(dfts, D = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You define a time series of length 144 with frequency equal to 17520 and then ask for a seasonal difference -- i.e., a difference between observations that are 17520 time periods apart -- which can't be done.

The error message is not very helpful -- I'll get that fixed.

Comment: The frequency in the original example has been edited to reflect this (half-hourly = 48*365 = 17520), however I now just get an error message.

Comment: UPDATE: I have altered seasonality as per [this blog post](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/) and it now seems to be working.